# how to not repeat the same constructor in this class?

Tags: javascript, html, class, oop

I have a program that has a lot of similar classes.

the problem is that `G0`, `G1`, `G2`, and `G3` classes, have the same `constructor()` structure (but this some little differences)

```js
// this code is repeated on every child
this.x = _xyzObj.x ?? GcodeAPI.previusX ?? 0;
this.y = _xyzObj.y ?? GcodeAPI.previusY ?? 0;
this.z = _xyzObj.z ?? GcodeAPI.previusZ ?? 0;
```

**but where is the problem?**

normally for calling the class I use something like this

```js
new G1({x:1, y:2, z: 10}).getCode();
```

As you see in the example,

the `G1` class takes as parameters an object of data.

as this happens the same for the other child classes like

 `G0`, `G1`, `G2`, `G3`, and so on...

---

I am interested to see if there is a way to

put the repetitive `constructor()` code inside the parent class (`Gcommands`)

✅ like I did for the methods (`getCode();`)

... and yes, I tried, but...

since the object of data came from the child class,

the parent class can't access the child variables

(like we did with `super();` for getting the parent var from a child... but we can't do the opposite)

```js
class GcodeAPI {
}

class Gcommands extends GcodeAPI {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.lineOfCode = "⚠️ No line of code - please use getLine() method first";
  }

  getCode() {
    this.setLastPosition();
    this.lineOfCode = `${this.prefix} X${this.x} Y${this.y} Z${this.z}`;
    return this.lineOfCode;
  }

  setLastPosition() {
    GcodeAPI.previusX = this.x;
    GcodeAPI.previusY = this.y;
    GcodeAPI.previusZ = this.z;
  }
}

class G0 extends Gcommands {
  constructor(_xyzObj) {
    super();
    // these line are repetitive
    this.x = _xyzObj.x ?? GcodeAPI.previusX ?? 0;
    this.y = _xyzObj.y ?? GcodeAPI.previusY ?? 0;
    this.z = _xyzObj.z ?? GcodeAPI.previusZ ?? 0;

    this.prefix = `G0`;
  }
}

class G1 extends Gcommands {
  constructor(_xyzObj) {
    super();
    // these line are repetitive
    this.x = _xyzObj.x ?? GcodeAPI.previusX ?? 0;
    this.y = _xyzObj.y ?? GcodeAPI.previusY ?? 0;
    this.z = _xyzObj.z ?? GcodeAPI.previusZ ?? 0;

    this.prefix = `G1`;
  }
}

class G2 extends Gcommands { 
  constructor(_xyzObj) {
    super();
    // these line are repetitive
    this.x = _xyzObj.x ?? GcodeAPI.previusX ?? 0;
    this.y = _xyzObj.y ?? GcodeAPI.previusY ?? 0;
    this.z = _xyzObj.z ?? GcodeAPI.previusZ ?? 0;

    this.prefix = `G2`;
  }
}

class G3 extends Gcommands {
  constructor(_xyzObj) {
    super();
    // these line are repetitive
    this.x = _xyzObj.x ?? GcodeAPI.previusX ?? 0;
    this.y = _xyzObj.y ?? GcodeAPI.previusY ?? 0;
    this.z = _xyzObj.z ?? GcodeAPI.previusZ ?? 0;

    this.prefix = `G3`;
  }
}

console.log(new G3({ x: 1, y: 2, z: 3 }).getLine());
```

---

basically, I want a code similar to this,

but I don't know what is the syntax for making

the object parameter be in child class

but the variable in the parent class.

```js
class GcodeAPI {}

class Gcommands extends GcodeAPI {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.lineOfCode = "⚠️ No line of code - please use getLine() method first";

    // here are the repetitive classes
    this.x = _xyzObj.x ?? GcodeAPI.previusX ?? 0;
    this.y = _xyzObj.y ?? GcodeAPI.previusY ?? 0;
    this.z = _xyzObj.z ?? GcodeAPI.previusZ ?? 0;
  }

  getCode() {
    this.setLastPosition();
    this.lineOfCode = `${this.prefix} X${this.x} Y${this.y} Z${this.z}`;
    return this.lineOfCode;
  }

  setLastPosition() {
    GcodeAPI.previusX = this.x;
    GcodeAPI.previusY = this.y;
    GcodeAPI.previusZ = this.z;
  }
}

class G0 extends Gcommands {
  constructor(_xyzObj) {
    super();
    this.prefix = `G0`;
  }
}

class G1 extends Gcommands {
  constructor(_xyzObj) {
    super();

    this.prefix = `G1`;
  }
}

class G2 extends Gcommands {
  constructor(_xyzObj) {
    super();

    this.prefix = `G2`;
  }
}

class G3 extends Gcommands {
  constructor(_xyzObj) {
    super();

    this.prefix = `G3`;
  }
}
```

---

if you need some testing examples:

```js
console.log(
  new G0({
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
  }).getCode(),
);

console.log(
  new G1({
    x: 3,
    y: 4,
  }).getCode(),
);

console.log(
  new G2({
    x: 5,
  }).getCode(),
);

console.log(
  new G3({
    z: 6,
  }).getCode(),
);

console.log(
  new G1({
    x: 7,
    y: 8,
    z: 9,
  }).getCode(),
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass **_xyzObj** to super so that it is accessible.

```js
class GcodeAPI {
  constructor(_xyzObj) {
    this.lineOfCode = "⚠️ No line of code - please use getLine() method first";
    this.x = _xyzObj.x ?? this.previusX ?? 0;
    this.y = _xyzObj.y ?? this.previusY ?? 0;
    this.z = _xyzObj.z ?? this.previusZ ?? 0;
  }
}

class Gcommands extends GcodeAPI {
  getCode() {
    this.setLastPosition();
    this.lineOfCode = `${this.prefix} X${this.x} Y${this.y} Z${this.z}`;
    return this.lineOfCode;
  }

  setLastPosition() {
    GcodeAPI.previusX = this.x;
    GcodeAPI.previusY = this.y;
    GcodeAPI.previusZ = this.z;
  }
}

class G0 extends Gcommands {
  constructor(_xyzObj) {
    super(_xyzObj);
    this.prefix = "G0";
  }
}

class G1 extends Gcommands {
  constructor(_xyzObj) {
    super(_xyzObj);
    this.prefix = "G1";
  }
}

class G2 extends Gcommands {
  constructor(_xyzObj) {
    super(_xyzObj);
    this.prefix = "G2";
  }
}

class G3 extends Gcommands {
  constructor(_xyzObj) {
    super(_xyzObj);
    this.prefix = "G3";
  }
}

console.log(
  new G0({
    x: 1,
    y: 2,
  }).getCode(),
);

console.log(
  new G1({
    x: 3,
    y: 4,
  }).getCode(),
);

console.log(
  new G2({
    x: 5,
  }).getCode(),
);

console.log(
  new G3({
    z: 6,
  }).getCode(),
);

console.log(
  new G1({
    x: 7,
    y: 8,
    z: 9,
  }).getCode(),
);
```

Comment: @stackdeveloper I undeleted it. I deleted it because I copied your sample code and it was all errors and I didn't see why at first. I undeleted it once I realized you had changed the function name after your initial question was posted.

Comment: thanks seem to work fine! never think that `super()` can do also the opposite :)